# Update Lambda function code with inline code using SDK

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm trying to update AWS Lambda Function with code provided as string, not a local file. I use v3 sdk libraries

```
  client.updateFunctionCode({
    FunctionName: "myFunc",
    ZipFile: Buffer.from("console.log('hey')", "base64")
  })
```

But I get an error:

> Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to
> upload again.

Official documentation:

> If the function's package type is Zip, then you must specify the
> deployment package as a .zip file archive. Enter the Amazon S3 bucket
> and key of the code .zip file location. **You can also provide the
> function code inline using the ZipFile field**.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or this functionality isn't supported by AWS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in Python CDK -

```
lambda_.Function(stack, "MyLayeredLambda",
    code=lambda_.InlineCode("foo"),
    handler="index.handler",
    runtime=lambda_.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
    layers=[layer]
)
```

Comment: this is CDK, not SDK

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution. It turned out that all I needed to do was create a function capable of compressing all the files along with their contents into memory, and then pass that buffer string along.

```
import archiver from 'archiver';
import { Writable } from 'stream';

// Define a type for the objects in the files array
export type FileContent = {
  name: string;
  content: string;
};

export function zipFiles(files: FileContent[]): Promise<Buffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const buffs: Buffer[] = [];

    const converter = new Writable({
      write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        buffs.push(chunk as Buffer); // Assure TypeScript that `chunk` is a Buffer
        process.nextTick(callback);
      },
    });

    converter.on('finish', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(buffs));
    });

    const archive = archiver('zip', {
      zlib: { level: 9 }, // Compression level
    });

    archive.on('error', (err: Error) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    archive.pipe(converter);

    files.forEach((file) => {
      archive.append(Buffer.from(file.content), { name: file.name });
    });

    archive.finalize();
  })
}
```

And finally, this line works:

```
client.updateFunctionCode({
 FunctionName: "my-func",
 ZipFile: zip
})
```